# Save current slide, no fonts

Tags: vba, filesystems, powerpoint

This is a piece of code I wrote to save the current slide with no embedded fonts into a single

I think something with the path is wrong because it seems to mix-up a Onedrive path with the rest of the path and filename I add.  And though it confirms the file has been saved, I can't find it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
    Option Explicit
    
    Sub SaveCurrentSlide()
    
    Dim CurrentSlide As String
    Dim tPath As String
    Dim tFilename As String
    
    CurrentSlide = ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex
    On Error GoTo errorhandler

    If ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewNormal Then ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Activate

    With ActivePresentation
        ' Build a unique filename and save a coy of the now single-slide presentation
        tPath = .Path
        tFilename = tPath & "\" & Left(.Name, InStrRev(.Name, ".") - 1) & " [slide " & CurrentSlide & "].pptx"
        ActivePresentation.SaveAs FileName:=tFilename, _
        FileFormat:=ppSaveAsPresentation, EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=msoFalse
    End With
    
    ' Give feedback to the user
    MsgBox "Current slide exported to:" & vbNewLine & tFilename, vbOKOnly, "Export Current Slide - Export Complete"
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

errorhandler:
          Debug.Print Err, Err.Description
          Resume Next
          End Sub
```

Comment: Just because you change the _view_ to one slide doesn't mean you're saving just that slide. You're saving the whole presentation. Have you tried stepping through the code one line at a time?

Comment: @JohnKorchok Hello John. I get the first part of your question. The second part, not so much.  I've read the code line by line several times before posting. I just can't figure it out.

Comment: If you use SaveAs, you would have to delete all the other slides first, use SaveAs, then undo. Here's a page with a complete macro: https://powerpointprogram.indezine.com/2019/10/powerpoint-vba-export-slides-to-single-slide-presentations.html